# How to exclude unused libraries from code coverage report?

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

There's something I apparently don't understand about PHPUnit's code coverage whitelisting.

I have the following filter for a couple of folders:

```
<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
        <directory suffix=".php">./lib</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

- "app" - I want to know about anything not covered in here so I've enabled `addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` for the core application. (this works as expected)
- "lib" - I want to see what was covered in files **used** from here but there will be a lot that isn't used, so I've disabled `addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` for the library files. (this I have a problem with)

What happens is that **library files not included at runtime** show up in the reports as unexecuted code. I can verify the code is not included during test by adding lines that would throw fatal errors.

This result seems contradictory to what the PHPUnit docs say, but no doubt I'm doing it wrong. Can anyone explain how I can include my executed library code, but only that which was required during test?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `filter` node in the `phpunit.xml`. I have used the following file in a project. It whitelist's local files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
  backupStaticAttributes="false"
  syntaxCheck="false"
  bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php" 
>
<php>
  <includePath>lib/php</includePath>
</php>
<filter>
  <whitelist>
    <directory suffix=".php">lib/php/</directory>
  </whitelist>
</filter>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite name="Jm_Log">
     <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<logging>
  <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="jam"
   charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
   lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
  <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
  <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>
</phpunit>
```

Note: You can also use a blacklist.

Comment: I don't understand how your answer addresses my question. I am using a filter, as my example shows.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. Probably I posted too fast. I would need to reproduce your problem. I will do after work and give you a better answer.

Comment: There were recently a couple of PHPUnit (PHP_CodeCoverage, actually) versions in which the whitelist filtering was broken. Please re-test with the latest version.

Comment: @Tim Oh, I missed to come back to you. But I don't think that I can help more than Sebastian :)

Comment: Just updated from 4.5 to 4.7.3 and I have the same issue. I can share my test case if you have a BitBucket username.

Comment: @Tim Its hek2mgl also on Bitbucket